# imakeidx and \renewcommand{\thepage} incompatibility

Tags: indexing

I am writing a long document in LaTeX and I am using `imakeidx` for indexing contents. All works find. I'm compiling in xelatex and when I used the command:

`\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\arabic{page}}\hfill{\roman{page}}}`

Like this:

```
\chapter{{First chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\arabic{page}}\hfill{\roman{page}}}
 \setcounter{page}{1}
```

Then the indexing stops working.

It costed me long time to figure out it was this the problem... It was good because I managed to clean the preamble of packages I'm not really using.

Does anyone could give me light on why there is incompatibility?
Thank you in advance

EDITION TO HELP UNDERSTANDING
The next code produces the INDEX

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book} % \documentclass es lo primero que se pone en un documento de latex. Este comando me sirve para decirle a latex si lo que estoy haciendo es un libro, un reporte, un artículo, etc.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Autor 1\\[1cm]{\small Boos: Boos2}}
\title{My document}
\date{\today}
\makeindex 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Teoric}
\index{scientific}  \index{dynamic!system}  \index{economic!system}  \index{music}.
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
3+2=5
\end{equation}

\printindex
 
\end{document}
```

The next code does NOT produce the INDEX

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book} % \documentclass es lo primero que se pone en un documento de latex. Este comando me sirve para decirle a latex si lo que estoy haciendo es un libro, un reporte, un artículo, etc.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Autor 1\\[1cm]{\small Boos: Boos2}}
\title{My document}
\date{\today}
\makeindex 

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\chapter{Teoric}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\arabic{page}}\hfill{\roman{page}}}
\index{scientific}  \index{dynamic!system}  \index{economic!system}  \index{music}.
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
3+2=5
\end{equation}

\printindex
 
\end{document}
```

The only difference is the line

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\arabic{page}}\hfill{\roman{page}}}
```

The first code does not include both indoarabic and roman numbers in the pages but it can make the INDEX with `\printindex`. The second code does NOT print the INDEX with `\printindex` but it does include both indoarabic and roman numbers.

This is why I meant that stop working.

Comment: "stops working" is impossible to debug, do you mean you got an error or that the page numbers were wrong or??? It is always best to provide an example that shows the problem.  The definition is rather strange and quite likely to break most indexes and tables of contents,  you are printing the number twice with infinite stretch glue every time you print the page number in any context?????

Comment: Did you try `\tableofcontents`? Anyway, how's the index supposed to manage this doubled page number? If you really want to print a double format page number, you should do it as part of the header/footer definitions, not redefining `\thepage`.

Comment: with your definition a text such as `see the figure on page \pageref{zzz}` will produce "see the figure on page 2______________________________ii"  for any reference that uses a page number,  similarly the table of contents will print every page number of every section twice, what is the intention of the definition?

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comments, I have added the code in an edited question.

Comment: Dear @egreg thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle about your second comment. I need to print the pages in both indoarabic and roman because I am constantly working with text in english and latin.

Comment: sorry that comment is hard to understand. Why do you want to print the page number twice in every reference to a page number? The answer will be do not use that definition but without knowing what you wanted it to do it is hard to tell you what to do instead.

Comment: not only the index the page head has [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCheg.png) and the table of contents [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCjBK.png)

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle the text I added is very small. I am writing my thesis and I am constantly working in Latin and English. So, I print both numbers everywhere: In the chapters, in the list of contents, in the pages, in the sections, etc., it all works. The only thing that fails is the generation of the index. When I remove the the both numbers command then it generates the index, when I add it, all works fine except the index.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is a dummy text that wrote there for you to see where the index fails. In my thesis it compiles properly fine. I get 
Contents
Something                           1 I
Something else                    2 II
etc.
I have been working on my preamble and configuration for long. The problem is adding the index.

Comment: Dear @egreg Thank you for your answer. It works just perfectly. I'm quite happy with it thank you. To make it run I removed the lines:

````
\NewCommandCopy{\hyperpageoriginal}{\hyperpage}
\renewcommand{\hyperpage}[1]{%
  \hyperpageoriginal{#1\ \romannumeral#1}%
}
````
and it is just perfect. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

making `\thepage` print the page number twice would make `\pageref` (and similar constructs such as tables of contents and lists of tables) unusable.

Presumably the intention is to have the arabic and latin form in the page head (although this is also rather unusual) that can be specified directly without redefining `\thepage`

```
\documentclass{book} % \documentclass es lo primero que se pone en un documento de latex. Este comando me sirve para decirle a latex si lo que estoy haciendo es un libro, un reporte, un artículo, etc.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Autor 1\\[1cm]{\small Boos: Boos2}}
\title{My document}
\date{\today}
\makeindex 
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\newcommand{\thepagetwice}{\arabic{page}\hfill\roman{page}}

\makeatletter
\def\@evenhead{\thepagetwice\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepagetwice}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Teoric}

\index{scientific}  \index{dynamic!system}  \index{economic!system}  \index{music}.
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
3+2=5
\end{equation}

\printindex
 
\end{document}
```

This has the duplicated number in the page head

[image]

and a usable index

[image]

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your answer, I will study it carefully I'm sure this will help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When `\index` does its job it writes out a line of the form

```
\indexentry{scientific|hyperpage}{5}
```

and the last braced group ***must*** contain a single number (in whatever supported format). In your case it will contain `{5\hfill v}` which is illegal.

This seems to work, but I believe you should reconsider the problem and solve it in a different way: you get scores of warnings.

Oh, the links won't work at all. But that's another story.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Autor 1\\[1cm]{\small Boos: Boos2}}
\title{My document}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}\hfill\roman{page}}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\HyInd@org@wrindex{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}{}{}
\makeatother

\NewCommandCopy{\hyperpageoriginal}{\hyperpage}
\renewcommand{\hyperpage}[1]{%
  \hyperpageoriginal{#1\ \romannumeral#1}%
}

\makeindex 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Teoric}
\section{whatever}
\index{scientific}  \index{dynamic!system}  \index{economic!system}  \index{music}.
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
3+2=5
\end{equation}

\printindex
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @egreg thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't manage to get it to work. I keep getting: 

` Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \NewCommandCopy
                    {\hyperpageoriginal}{\hyperpage}`

can't figure why.